# make JSP Declaration stateless

Tags: java, jsp, session, scope

Consider the following jsp:

```
<%!
    private String firstName = "";
    private String lastName = "";

    private String formatName(){
        return lastName + ", " + firstName;
    }
%>
<%
    firstName = request.getParameter("FNAME");
    lastName = request.getParameter("LNAME");
    String formattedName = formatName();
    out.print(formattedName);
%>
```

Is there a way to make the declaration section <%! (...) %> stateless? That is I want firstName and lastName to be unique to each page load. I am not concerned with performance or best practice, refactor is not an option right now. I'm looking for something like <%@ page persist="false" %>. Any suggestions?

Comment: No because that's pretty much the purpose of the declaration. You want something to happen on every page load, stick it in the scriptlet part.

Comment: @pvg the reason it was done this way in the first place was because you cannot declare methods in the scriptlet part. Is there a syntax for declaring methods in a scriptlet-like scope?

Comment: No. Because declarations go in the declaration part. In the example you've given, it's not clear why you don't just declare the vars as local and pass them as params to your formatter. The instance vars seem completely superfluous.

Comment: @pvg imagine 20 methods all referring to the class-variables "firstName" and "lastName". The existing scriptlet code is expecting the class-variables to already exist. The solution I've come up with is to move mostly everything to a .java and pass the class the request, response, session, etc. it needs. Basically I need a new instance of what's inside the declaration tags every time the page loads.

Comment: Intellij IDEA could have trivially refactored that for you. The issue here is the lifecycle of the servlet (what a JSP page is).  It's one instance stateless instance that gets reused a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to accomplish what the example appears to want to accomplish, you don't need the instance variables at all. You could write this as

```
<%!
    private String formatName(String firstName, String lastName){
        return lastName + ", " + firstName;
    }
%>
<%
    String formattedName = formatName(request.getParameter("FNAME"),
                                      request.getParameter("LNAME"));
    out.print(formattedName);
%>
```

Comment: this may help someone else, but is irrelevant to my specific problem. I am trying to avoid refactoring all my existing methods into accepting arguments.

Comment: Ok, I guess your specific problem is unclear. You have a bunch of mis-written JSP and want to fix it by... not fixing it? Whatever the answer that almost certainly won't help anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

pvg is 100% correct that this shouldn't be done, and I probably won't use this solution, however I did come up with a solution that allows the methods to be moved without having them take new arguments. It may be useful for others to know that the following is **possible**, but not best practice.

```
<%!
    public class MyHandler
    {
        public HttpServletRequest objRequest = null;
        public HttpSession objSession = null;
        public HttpServletResponse objResponse = null;
        public JspWriter objOut = null;

        private String firstName = "";
        private String lastName = "";
        private String formatName(){
            return lastName + ", " + firstName;
        }
        public void go()
        {
            firstName = objRequest.getParameter("FNAME");
            lastName = objRequest.getParameter("LNAME");
            String formattedName = formatName();
            objOut.print(formattedName);            
        }
    }
%>
<%
    MyHandler myHandler = new MyHandler();
    myHandler.objRequest = request;
    myHandler.objSession = session;
    myHandler.objResponse = response;
    myHandler.objOut = out;
    myHandler.go();
%>
```